# Prove the for the following sets: ∀ sets A, B, and C, (A ∪ B) ∩ C ⊆ A ∪ (B ∩ C)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

∀ sets A, B, and C, (A ∪ B) ∩ C ⊆ A ∪ (B ∩ C)

Prove the following statement by using an element argument, reasoning directly
from the definitions of union and intersection, or algebraically making sure to explain each equivalency.

So I don't really know where to start or how to get this done. Every similar problem I have ever done relates to elements belonging to sets. Please Help.

Comment: Suppose $x\in (A\cup B)\cap C$.  Then that means that... Which means that... which in particular means that... from which it follows that $x\in A\cup (B\cap C)$

Comment: Alternatively, for more of an algebraic point of view., recall that intersection distributes over union, that is that $(A\cup B)\cap C = (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$ and try to reach a conclusion that way

Comment: Use the distributive law an the set on the left. One of the sets that results is a subset of $A.$

Comment: @JMoravitz - Sorry! I guess we were typing over each other.

Comment: If $A \subseteq C$, then the inclusion is even an equality, known as the "modular law". Any distributive lattice is modular, but not conversely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Let: $$x\in(A\cup B)\cap C\tag1$$ (i.e $x\in A\cup B$ and $x\in C$).

On base of $(1)$ prove that $x\in A\cup(B\cap C)\tag2$ (i.e. $x\in A$ or $x\in B\cap C$)